# Why am I getting the same result from Anova and aov_car in R, and why is it different from SPSS?

Tags: r, statistics, spss, anova

I am conducting a reanalysis of some data. The dv is continuous (beta value ie neural activity) and the iv is categorical (position) with three levels (1, 2, 3). Position is set as a factor. It is repeated measures, and there are 126 observations. The original analysis was done in SPSS, and I am trying to replicate those results with R.

I don't understand how to make a MRE of this, so my data from dput is at the bottom.

My ANOVA results are different from those reported in the original paper (the data is identical). Specifically, they reported F(2,82) = 18.262, p = 0.00, but my table (below) is totally different. I used the `Anova` function, and now get the impression that I should be using `aov_car` but the output is the same between the two.

```
> Anova(lm(Beta ~ Position, data = stack_ex))
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: Beta
           Sum Sq  Df F value Pr(>F)
Position    60.57   2  1.5213 0.2225
Residuals 2448.70 123
```

```
> aov_car(Beta ~ Position + Error(Beta), data = stack_ex)
Contrasts set to contr.sum for the following variables: Position
Anova Table (Type 3 tests)

Response: Beta
    Effect     df   MSE    F  ges p.value
1 Position 2, 123 19.91 1.52 .024    .222
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I didn't know what to use as the error term, so I put Beta. Is this the issue?

Here is the data, apologies for not being able to reduce it down.

```
> dput(stack_ex)
structure(list(Beta = c(9.97627322506813, 4.51007015616003, 12.5899137493145, 
5.16107528902195, 0.69934803628816, 3.05576441003722, 9.73415586595716, 
3.48253752326239, 8.72271400892749, 6.58254223482513, 9.64252595049282, 
6.2575247824253, 5.55086088416984, 3.26575073266956, -0.189486641765607, 
-6.34627220217585, 3.03699535774724, 5.38452950644857, 7.2247809046584, 
1.05684383099248, 0.745997758871227, 13.4708766693015, 6.22313273382721, 
7.60691743953363, 7.95869706610072, 0.0733745510036445, 5.74455260852637, 
9.10243217750976, 3.83463985621549, 6.51540068169028, 6.74657874951813, 
9.06748922888841, 4.18661204617864, 8.13865720827057, 4.97289378228525, 
4.79399790512039, -12.5433736154914, 3.22520674616528, 4.83924807559523, 
6.89780284608954, 2.01175994751707, 1.58936731656692, 8.65646845487533, 
2.03332866864119, 6.59573013233866, 4.35624613417537, 3.22584501764675, 
3.01812749198894, 8.67739700219412, 5.14273744714805, 7.54959191256081, 
7.83244934217214, 8.67126128885367, 3.99955715822518, 2.95804569815409, 
2.25327292671231, 0.258342636171449, -6.87648408967595, 1.9848049507549, 
2.45033479610578, 7.41525416520838, 1.11896377050173, 0.0698315480648937, 
9.90975895502056, 5.03717210651178, 4.67127493715398, 7.90306051043896, 
3.0618932143297, 5.43781266582611, 8.9383987897543, 4.7982992164727, 
6.90576740201611, 4.43862196057089, 9.06484925843098, 3.35645527138813, 
5.42103905597134, 2.32859166774007, 3.65962841104834, -11.716124636774, 
7.15256990819002, 4.02640955184303, 7.10747478179406, 2.81026958853589, 
1.21494403713035, 9.06256308202033, 2.40170878761068, 6.45729748790901, 
4.88232212084591, 1.55722661655526, 3.09556060018938, 6.6629967466337, 
4.38848062553557, 4.38871083406173, 6.40367918458127, 6.361735558817, 
4.21279189431753, 2.08838813524482, 2.21632202746396, -0.491401226521853, 
-7.3685373528786, 2.12839354041543, 4.22958686769682, 4.25606944426722, 
0.330400668298046, 1.02776552933976, 10.6734745608271, 3.01238218831987, 
4.03318609054561, 6.45849154079659, 0.45593329021199, 5.76390726591623, 
7.21202360734704, 4.62140561321984, 3.72714943200746, 5.49911004676976, 
9.15658405382221, 3.25231083403689, 3.67627240704932, 3.48390458422993, 
2.98674297337782, -19.5189775914798, 2.59812967326379, 2.78334604762499, 
3.70635047793331, -0.223282095324164, 2.17552096286021), Position = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -126L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: If it really is a repeated measures design (you haven't given us enough information to be sure), then you're missing at least one independent variable - the variable within which the measures are repeated.  This probably also explains why you're getting different F-statistics: in a repeated measures design there are typically (at least) two levels of variation (one between "subjects" and one within "subjects") at hence at least two error terms.  I suggest you check your data and then repost to cross validated for more detailed advice.

Comment: ... and, no, Beta cannot be both the dependent variable and the error term.

Comment: @Limey Thank you for your response. What should my error term be? Related to between and within subjects, beta values here are the means of beta values averaged across participant for each level of position. I think that means that subject was the between subjects variable, but they've already been averaged. Does that clarify things?

Comment: You've given us code but not context - that is the *design* of your experiment.  So it's impossible to answer your question definitively.  It sounds like subject should be in the model.  I don't understand you can "average across position" and include position in the model at the same time.  That's a contradiction.  I repeat my advice to clarify your situation and post on CrossValidated, since your problem relates to design rather than coding.  I will not respond further.

Comment: Just for the record, I said the Beta values are averaged across participant (subject), not position.

Comment: Indeed you did.  That was a typo on my part.  Apologies.  Nevertheless, my point still stands.